# How to launch scripts in browser from PhpStorm with correct address?

Tags: php, phpstorm

Test scripts are located in `...\Apache\htdocs\myproject.local\web\tests\`, `web` in PhpStorm project is marked as Resources, for Apache it is site's DocumentRoot,  everywhere in PhpStorm settings server is set to `myproject.local:80` (domain of my web-application on the local server), but when I launch script from PhpStorm using `Open in browser` I see address like this:

```
http://localhost:49845/myproject.local/tests/NativeSandbox.php
```

Where did it come from? I need address like

```
http://myproject.local/tests/NativeSandbox.php
```

How can I get this?

P.S. PHPUnit, Xdebug, and console launching scripts in PhpStorm works well.

Comment: Please define Deployment entry (e.g. "In place" type; make sure that you fill all fields on all tabs) and mark it as Default for this project -- URL will be taken from there. If it's not defined (like in your case) then PhpStorm's own built-in simple web server is used.

Comment: It's strange. I have only coverage and debugging subtrees in Deployment section. No Mapping or Connections like in manual...

Comment: Screenshots please. My remote-mind-reading-helmet is charging up till next morning...

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/93067701/fgdf.PNG

Comment: Make sure that standard "Remote Hosts Access" plugin is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create and configure Deployment entry (e.g. `In place` type should be just fine; just make sure that you fill all fields on first 2 tabs) and mark it as Default for this project -- URL will be taken from there.

Without deployment entry (like in your case) PhpStorm will use own built-in simple web server (custom port is used (typically 643342) + project name is in the path).