# Does phpstorm has it's own php interpreter?

Tags: php, server, localhost, phpstorm

I am currently using PhpSTorm 10.0.2 on windows 10.
I do have wamp installed but I barely open it since I know PhpStorm has it's own local server installed.  Knowing this by when run / debug the page, the link goes to `localhost:63342` but when I run php scripts it'll say my interpreter isn't set up yet but I have no idea where to find the php folder.  (I am able to set it up using the php in wamp) but I am wondering if I don't have wamp installed, I should still be able to use set up the php interpreter without installing anything extra right?  If true, where is the php folder?

Comment: You have to have your own PHP installed on your computer -- it does not matter where you will take it from (PHP site or part of another package (e.g. WAMP/XAMPP/etc) -- it just has to be fully working.

Comment: @LazyOne ah ok, as mentioned I do have wamp installed and if I set the php intercepter to wamp it'll work but I just thought phpstorm also has it's own that's why when debugging / running the script the link is always`localhost:port#`

Comment: That `localhost:63342` means that you are using PhpStorm's own built-in simple web server, which requires properly configured PHP Interpreter defined in PhpStorm settings. If you want to use your WAMP instead -- just define Deployment entry (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/35244934/783119) -- you may just need to delete or alter your already created Run/Debug Configurations (in case if that URL was saved there).

Answer (score 1):

No,Use xammp(rec),ampps,wamp,or download from PHP site php interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

You can see more details of how to setup a PHP local or remote interpretter here: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/enabling-php-support.html

hope this helps